# What should be included in a batch script to acquire IoC for a Windows PC?

Tags: windows, security, batch-file, computer-forensics

I want to hunt for the Indicators of Compromise (IoC) in a potentially infected Windows PC.

I am writing a batch script that would record the information needed for analysis. It includes the following CMD commands:

```
time /T
date /T
whoami 

systeminfo

net user 
dir /a "C:\Users\" 
net localgroup administrators 
net group administrators 

net start
schtasks  
tasklist  
tasklist -svc  
tasklist -v  
wmic process list full 
wmic product get name
```

- What else should I be looking for?
- The script would be written in a way to create a new file for each
  command separated by directories such as 'Network Artifacts',
  'Processes & Services', 'Machine Info' etc. What can I do to improve 
  the script?
- Do you suggest taking registry & memory dumps at this stage?

Comment: _"What else should I be looking for?"_ - software that already fulfills this purpose. You aren't going to get far by reinventing the wheel in a simple batch script. You're going to get a lot of false negatives.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you suggest any software for the said task?

Comment: Feel too broad for SO... Note that IoC more likely to stand for "Inversion Of Control" when used on programming site.

Answer (score 1):

I would also take a look at your services:

```
wmic service list brief
wmic service list full
```

reg keys:

```
reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

There are many other things you can search for as well (windows event logs with certain id, recently added items to the c:\windows and c:\windows\system32 folders.. maybe even a hash comparison of those directories to a known good state). If you expand this into a PowerShell script, then you can get a lot more out of it I believe.

You can take memory captures at any time. I recommend doing those as early as possible so that you do not leave too big of a footprint on the machine.

Comment: Thank you, @lytledw! 
You comment is helpful.

I also have a related question, however, how do you suggest I record the recently added items to specific directories.

Comment: you can do a dir /od . This will list everything in a directory in descending order based on date.

Comment: additionally, if you wanted to use powershell you could do something along the lines of: 
get-childitem c:\windows\*.* -include *.dll | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-14)}

Answer (score 1):

I would take a memory image before doing anything else, and if possible try to grab the pagefile. You will need to be running the commands from an administrator command shell in order to be able to copy the pagefile.

Lytledw's answer is good **as long as you remember to grab the memory image as early in the process as possible**, in order to minimize your impact on what's running.